# How to use tensorflow serving?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am learning to use Tensorflow serving but I have a very hard time finding examples including in Stackoverflow.

I am using flower example in TensorFlow website. The training part is successful and having a hard time deploying.

I ran the server as follows :

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=C:\tmp\saved_models,target=/models/flowers -e MODEL_NAME=flowers -t tensorflow/serving &
```

To look at all SignatureDef, I used the following

```
saved_model_cli show --dir c:\tmp\saved_models\1 --all
```

The response is

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['image'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: ()
        name: DecodeJpeg/contents:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (5)
        name: Const:0
    outputs['prediction'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 5)
        name: final_result:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

As I have seen [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) it suppose to have "Method name is: tensorflow/serving/classify"

Why is it missing in my example ?

My RESTAPI request is as follows :

```
http://localhost:8501/v1/models/flowers/versions/1:classify
```

Body :

```
{
  "signature_name": "serving_default",
  "flowers": [
    {
      "image": { "b64": "c:/Users/pubud/OneDrive/Pictures/bird.jpg=" },
      "rose": "flower"
    }
  ]
}
```

The error I get is :

```
{
    "error": "Expected classification signature method_name to be tensorflow/serving/classify. Was: tensorflow/serving/predict"
}
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RESTful URL specifies `...:classify`, which is different from what's in the signature_def['serving_default'] - `predict`.

Try changing the RESTful URL to be `...:predict`, and then refer to the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/api_rest#predict_api) for the json body of the request.

Here is more information about the SignatureDefs:
https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/signature_defs

Good luck!

Comment: My intention of the training is to use Classify. Why am I missing classify? HOw do I set server to classify ?

Comment: The supported SignatureDefs are determined by the how the model's output is defined, and not every model is designed to support both. The classify SignatureDef requires ` two optional output Tensors: classes and scores, at least one of which must be present.` If the flower model's output does not conform to such, then it won't support classify.